# Common Table Expression is extreme slow within functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, sql-server-2019

I have an SQL function which also contains a cursor. Within the cursor, I have initially a table variable I was using which joins with a main table just using left outer join. It was working fine. But when data getting dumbed the table gets bigger. Now the table has around 50k records. So of course when the table variable joins with the main table, everything starts dragging. I have tried the same outside the function using #temp variables. It works 30x faster.

But in SQL server it is not allowing insert into the #temp table. So that door is blocked.

Then I tried CTE with the same performance as the table variable. Very slow.

Ultimately I need a table to be returned. So a function is my only choice I guess.

Please help me to override this bottleneck. Now my function takes 4 minutes. At the same time when using normal tables or temp tables instead of table variable and CTE it's only 30-40 seconds.

Please ignore the cursor there. I disabled it (for one round) and still then at the time of joining with the CTE the query is slowing down. WHen I replace it with real table after inserting the same data from table variable or CTEs, then joining works super quick.

Comment: You have a cursor.  If you care about performance, that is the place to start.

Comment: You have provided no examples of your actual code, cursor, function or process, there is nothing to go on other than to say remove the cursor and find a set-based solution - that  will almost certainly improve performance by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The cursor is just a 3 round one. Cursors are slow, but its not in my case.. I tested the same without cursor and the CTE (or table variable) when joins with the min table causing the drag. Its not happening when real tables or #temp tables

Comment: @Stu Ignore the cursor, because I disabled the cursor for a single round executing. The joining part with CTE/Table variable made its dragging

Comment: The only other suggestion is to use a temp table instead of a table variable, as you have already discovered; table variables have many issues with estimates causing poor execution plans, even in 2019. Functions can be inlined under certain conditions but generally cause performance issues or force serial execution.

Comment: Without providing the query, or the execution plan (via paste the plan) what are you hoping for here?

Comment: What error do you get when you try inserting into a temporary table?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Side effecting operation create table

Comment: Why aren't you using a stored procedure instead of a function?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock We cant call stored procedure straight because functions are intended for readonly, but stored procedures are not. So the same error will trigger. Side-Effecting operator!

Comment: Stored procedures do not have the restriction that they cannot change database state, so you will not get the same error. I really do not understand why you can't use an SP

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I tried inset exec, which does triggered the same when trying insert from SP

Comment: Yes if you call it from within a function. My question was why you are using a function as your main routine instead of a stored procedure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233284/discussion-between-jonathan-willcock-and-sandeep-thomas).

Comment: @JonathanWillcock The reason was I need to get some extra column within a select query using a tabular function with parameters being sent from the select query itself. Anyway as you suggested I am going to change everything to SP. Its a huge one. Unfortunately no scope other than that, isnt it.. Thanks boss.. cheers